# HTTPS POST calls are ignored by flask

Tags: docker, flask, https

i have 2 flask containers. one is listening on port 80 for http calls and the other one is listening on port 443 for https calls.
both are supposed to respond to GET and POST calls.
the http (port 80) server works fine for both GET and POST.
the https (port 443) server works fine for GET calls but from some unclear reason it seems that POST calls are blocked somewhere and don't go through to the flask server.

this is the app.py of the http flask server:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'u_path': ''}, methods=['GET',"POST"])
@app.route('/<path:u_path>', methods=['GET',"POST"])
def redirectChannels(u_path):
    print(repr(u_path))
    print(request.base_url)
    print(request.url)
    print(request.method)
    print(request.values)

    res = ""
    if request.method == "GET":
        ans = requests.get(request.url)
        res = ans.text
    elif request.method == "POST":
        res = requests.post(request.url, data=request.values)

    return res


@app.before_request
def log_request_info():
    print('Headers: %s', request.headers)
    print('Body: %s', request.get_data())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host ='0.0.0.0', port = 5000, debug = True)
```

and this is the app.py of the https flask server:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
import sys, traceback
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'u_path': ''}, methods=['GET','POST'])
@app.route('/<path:u_path>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def redirectChannels(u_path):
    print(repr(u_path))
    print(request.base_url)
    print(request.url)
    print(request.method)
    print(request.values)

    res = ""
    if request.method == "GET":
        ans = requests.get(request.url)
        res = ans.text
    elif request.method == "POST":
        res = requests.post(request.url, data=request.values)

    return res

@app.before_request
def log_request_info():
    print('Headers: %s', request.headers)
    print('Body: %s', request.get_data())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host ='0.0.0.0', port = 5000, debug = True, ssl_context='adhoc')
```

i actually think it can be related to a configuration in the containers port mapping. when running docker ps i'm getting this:
[docker ps result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl8lk.png)

not sure i understand the 443/tcp under PORTS in both containers and i believe it might be related to my problem. can anyone explain it?

Comment: Are both of these containers running on the same server at the same time? If so, both of your flask instances are listening on the same port (5000). Depending how you've got your container environment running, if they're both running on the same server with this configuration, I suspect you're actually only hitting one server.

Comment: they are both running on the same server but that's  not the problem. each one is listening to it's own port 5000. the external host is directing it's port 80 to one of the container's port 5000 and port 443 to the other container's port 5000